# Blender 2.8 - Panning in the viewport

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

Does anyone know the shortcuts to pan a scene horizontally or vertically in the viewport?

In 2.7, holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling the middle mouse button would let me pan horizontally or vertically, I can't seem to do that anymore in 2.8.

Comment: The same shortcuts (eg, <kbd>Shift</kbd>) seems to work fine for me (using 2.80 alpha) - although I do have 'emulate 3-button mouse' enabled so I don't know if that's a factor.

Comment: Enabled 'emulate 3-button mouse' option, still nothing. I am using 2.8 Alpha 2.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I don't know why it's not set up by default but you can change the "pan view direction" in: Preferences > Input > Keymap > 3d view > 3d view global and it will work

Answer (score 1):

It works differently. You need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and then just drag with the middle mouse button for panning